# JavaScript - Using Assign to inherit functions from multiple prototypes?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

The question, in detail is bellow. I've been reading the Mozilla guide on multiple inheritance and see that we can inherit methods from another constructors prototype method by using call or apply, to set the context, and by manually setting up the prototype as follows.

```
function Person(){
}
function Programmer(){
Person.call(this);
} 
Programmer.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

We can also do multiple inheritance by calling multiple constructors, but that just works on properties defined in the parent constructors. My question is, how does one inherit from multiple prototypes, properly? What if I use Object.Assign(), as follows.

```
function Person(){
}
function Programmer(){
}
function Employee(){
Person.call(this);
Programmer.call(this);
}

Object.assign(Employee.prototype, Person.prototype);
Object.assign(Employee.prototype, Devolper.prototype);
```

This would treat the Parent constructors as if they were Mixins, correct? Instead of pointing to parent prototype we copy the properties into the Employee prototype. Also, if parents have same named methods the order in which prototypes are assigned would come into play. We also don't have to scale the prototype link. We also don't need to set the constructor explicitly. `typeof` would not work, duck typing is better anyway.. rite? Thanks.

If my question has been answered, please close down. If question does not make sense, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's all correct (but keep reading), other than what I assume are typos in the question:

- It's `Object.create`, not `Object.Create`
- It's `Object.assign`, not `Object.Assign`
- You probably meant to use `Programmer.prototype` in the second call

You can also do it in one call:

```
Object.assign(Employee.prototype, Person.prototype, Programmer.prototype);
```

But yes, that uses `Person.prototype` and `Programmer.prototype` as mixins.